# How to set up Keycloak Client for 2 or more services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, client, keycloak

2 services both are secured, licensing service uses feign and sends a call to org service in one method(current access token sent via header)
my question is that one access token should have both client id so i can access the roles right
so 2 different keycloak clients but user only requests access for licensing service so how can i make access token work in both.
if i only make 1 client for both services what should be the base url?
licensing service url

```
http://localhost:8090
```

organization service url

```
http://localhost:8091
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set the Root URL like http://localhost:8080 in Keycloak
then multiple redirect URIs, including all service URLs. For example:
URI1: http://localhost:8090/*
URI2: http://localhost:8091/*